# bugzilla custom field mandatory

Tags: bugzilla

In our BugZilla (version 3.6.1) installation is a custom field that is currently mandatory. We want to set it to optional now but the edit mask does not offer this option. Is there another way to do that?

[image: The edit field menu]

Thanks

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "is mandatory"? Do you mean on bug creation, or edit, or both?

Comment: It has to be set on bug creation. it would be better if we could leave it blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a blank value as a legal field value, and make it the default (lowest sortkey).